# Why I need to put my phone to Gear VR to debug google cardboard app?

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am using Unity3d and when I press Export & Run after the loading my phone asking me to connect my phone to the Gear VR.

The app is only for Google Cardboard!

Comment: Can you not just export it to an Android device? That's what my dev team did.

Comment: I want to try it on android.. I will try export it and then put it in the phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to disable vr mode to build for cardboard. Go to `Edit > Project Settings > Player > Other Settings` and make sure to remove the checkmark next to `Virtual Reality Supported`. Also make sure to use the [Cardboard Prefab for Unity](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/download) to replace the camera.

Unity has [announced to support Cardboard without plugins](http://gamasutra.com/view/news/265660/Google_Cardboard_VR_gets_native_Unity_support.php) in the future, so this special setup will most likely no longer be necessary.